# Adding a Quiz Timer, Fade Out/Skip to the next if timer reaches 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I'm really new to jQuery but familiar with some other languages. I recently bought a quiz type script and I'm trying to add a simple 15 second timer to each question. It's only a fun quiz, so no need to worry about users playing with the javascript to increase time etc.

Basically, if a user does not pick a question within 15 seconds, it will automatically go on to the next question and the timer starts over again.

Answers have the `.next` tag, and when chosen it moves onto the next question as the code below shows (hopefully).

```
superContainer.find('.next').click(function () {

            $(this).parents('.slide-container').fadeOut(500, function () {
                $(this).next().fadeIn(500)
            });

            return false
});
```

The problem i have is if i use `setInterval`, i don't know how i can select the appropriate div again for fade it our and fade in the next one. I've tried the below code and a few similar scrappy idea's but it doesn't work, but maybe it will give a better idea of what I'm after though.

```
superContainer.find('.next').click(function () {

    $active_count = $count;

    countInterval = setInterval(function() {
                $active_count--;
                if($active_count <= 0){
                    clearInterval(countInterval);
                    $active_count = $count;
                    $(this).parents('.slide-container').fadeOut(500, function () {
                        $(this).next().fadeIn(500)
                    });
                }
                $('.question-timer').html($active_count);
            }, 1000);

            $(this).parents('.slide-container').fadeOut(500, function () {
                $(this).next().fadeIn(500)
            });

            return false
});
```

I've only been using JQuery a day or two so excuse any obvious mistakes and bad code! Let me know if you need any other code or information

Comment: Mhm, I assume when the user answers a quiz question, you'd reset the timer right? In that case I'd set a `setTimeout` every time a question is displayed and clear it whenever setting the next `setTimeout`. It isn't easy to post an answer without seeing a compilable example or having a very detailed info of the script though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is moderately tricky for a first jQuery project.

The knack (in this solution) is to factor out a `goNext` function that can be called in two ways - in response to a click event and in response to a 15 second `setTimeout()`, not `setInterval()`.

```
$(function(){
    var questionTimeout = null;

    function goNext($el) {
        clearTimeout(questionTimeout);
        var $next = $el.next();
        $el.fadeOut(500, function() {
            if($next.length > 0) {
                $next.fadeIn(500, function() {
                    questionTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                        goNext($next);
                    }, 15000);
                });
            }
            else {
                afterLastQuestion();
            }
        });
    }
    function afterLastQuestion(){
        alert("last question complete");
        $start.show();
    }

    var $superContainer = $("#superContainer").on('click', '.next', function() {
        goNext($(this).closest('.slide-container'));
        return false;
    });

    var $start = $("#start").on('click', function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $superContainer.find(".slide-container")
            .eq(0).clone(true,true)
            .prependTo(superContainer)
            .find(".next").trigger('click');
        return false;
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wAA9L/)

The process is started by clicking a "start" link, causing the first question to be cloned followed by a simulated click on the clone's "next" link. This ensures that the (actual) first question is treated in exactly the same way as all the others.

I also included a `afterLastQuestion()` function. Modify its action to do whatever is necessary after the last question is answered (or times out).

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the current question in a variable, resetting it on a `next` click and in the timer, e.g.

```
var $current;
superContainer.find('.next').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('.slide-container').fadeOut(500, function () {
        $(this).next().fadeIn(500);
        $current = $(this).next();
    });

});​
```

You'll just need to set it to your first question on initialisation, and remember to reset your timer on a `next` click

Also, it's usually preferable to use `e.preventDefault()` rather than `return false`.