# Iterate through array of objects (time dependent iteration) in jQuery/javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am a very beginner in javaScript and jQuery. I want to create a quiz game which has only two options.

I have an array of objects which look like this:

```
  var question = [];

    question[0] = {

        value: "someText here",
        ans: true
    };
```

I will write all my questions as an array of this object. It is a purely fun based game, so there are no issues if the user opens the source and reads the questions.
I want to use jQuery to show this question.
To show, I wrote this:

```
$("#someID").text(question[i].value); // where i is some random variable
```

Then I can call the .click method and check what button did user click and then handle the situation accordingly(changing the scores, decreasing the lives, etc). 
Now, I want to to iterate through this array of objects dependent on time, which means that, each question remains on the screen for 15 seconds or so, if user presses any of the two buttons, then next question appears immediately and other parameters are changed accordingly. However, if the user doesn't press any button for 15 seconds, next question should appear. How can I do this?

Efforts I have put myself before posting this question:

[Adding a Quiz Timer, Fade Out/Skip to the next if timer reaches 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118474/adding-a-quiz-timer-fade-out-skip-to-the-next-if-timer-reaches-0)

The first answer on this link tells me something which is close to what I want to achieve but it puts its data in the `<p>` tag,which I don't want. I strictly want to keep it as the array of objects.
Is there any way of achieving this? Thank You very much.

EDIT------

```
score=0; // variable to store the score of the user.
counter=0;



$(function () {
    fetchNextQuestion(); 

});

function fetchNextQuestion() {

    counter++;
    if (counter >= 5) {
        endTheGame();
    }
    else {

        number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
        $("#timer").text(question[number].value);
        _qtimer = setInterval(fetchNextQuestion(), 15000);
        userHasDoneSomething();
    }
}

function userHasDoneSomething() {

    $("#true").click(function () {
        clearInterval(_qtimer);
        if (question[number].ans === true) {
            score++;
        }
        else {
            score--;
        }

        fetchNextQuestion();
    });

    $("#false").click(function () {
        clearInterval(_qtimer);
        if (question[number].ans === false) {
            score++;
        }
        else {
            score--;
        }
        fetchNextQuestion();
    });


    return;



}



function endTheGame() {
    alert("The game has ended! Your score is "+ score);
}
```

Unfortunately, this piece of code doesn't work for me. It just gives me an alert box and the question doesn't change on screen. Any reasons where I am wrong? Note: There are no errors in web console.

EDIT #2---
Here is my HTML..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Serious or Joking</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="timer">
        <p>00</p>
    </div>


    <input type="button" value="true" class="answer" id="truebutton" />
    <input type="button" value="false" class="answer" id="falsebutton"/>


</body>
</html>
```

I am working in Visual Studio.

Comment: Can you show us what you so far? Without it we cant really help solve your problem

Comment: From your question it seems all you need is to change the [i] index to the next question if a user hasn't clicked in 15 seconds.. is that right?

Comment: @webkit yes, exactly.

Comment: Remove the `()` from `setInterval(fetchNextQuestion, 15000);` You're wanting to pass a callback function, not initialize it immediately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you just need an interval..

**EDIT:** Here's an update using your code:

```
var score=0, // variable to store the score of the user.
    counter=0;
    $(function () {
        fetchNextQuestion(); 
    });

    function fetchNextQuestion() {
        counter++;
        if (counter >= 5) {
            endTheGame();
        }
        else {
            number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
            $("#timer").text(question[number].value);
            _qtimer = setInterval(fetchNextQuestion, 15000);
            $(".answer").off().on('click', userHasDoneSomething);
        }
    }

    function userHasDoneSomething() {
        clearInterval(_qtimer);
        if (Boolean(question[number].ans) == Boolean(this.value))    score++;
        else                                    score--;

        fetchNextQuestion();
    }
    function endTheGame() {
        alert("The game has ended! Your score is "+ score);
    }
```

**Notice**: Give your #true and #false elements the same class (.answer)

Comment: Please read the edit I made to the question (based on your answer). Thank You.

Comment: Sure, I think the problem is that userHasDoneSomething() has to be called when an event has happend.. I'll update my answer and see if it works for ya

Comment: I think you'll also want to remove the `()` from the `setInterval(fetchNextQuestion, 15000);` line of code. You want to supply a callback function, not initialize the function immediately...

Comment: I used this code, but it shows me the alert box at the very beginning ( at the page load) "The game has ended! Your score is 0"  and when I get rid of alert box, the buttons don't work and only one question is being displayed. :(

Comment: @user3763293 The last comment by War10ck is probably what caused it, notice the change in the above code (removed the ()) and try again.. let me know the result

Comment: I removed the brackets, the alert box at the beginning is gone. The questions are changing at a gap of 15seconds (expected result) but clicking on the buttons is doing nothing at all.Any fix to this issue? I have added my html to the question as well. Thank You :)

Comment: yes, I was checking for your id's to be true/false.. I'll change it to value now that i see your html.. i've updated my answer. notice I only changed this.id to this.value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56273/discussion-between-webkit-and-user3763293).